# How to sort a tuple with a list inside?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to build a recommendation system content based.

I created this object which it's a tuple that contain a string and a list of tuples. Each tuple inside the list it's a couple of a score value and item id.

I don't know how to order this object by score value

```
    ('100460040',
 [(0.424943345091376, '100460139'),
  (0.5341613659423828, '100462023'),
  (0.2915704982169979, '100464122'),
  (0.6915704982169979, '100461026')])
```

This is the result I'm trying to get

```
        ('100460040',
 [(0.6915704982169979, '100461026'),
  (0.5341613659423828, '100462023'),
  (0.424943345091376, '100460139'),
  (0.2915704982169979, '100464122')])
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-or-object-with-sorted-in-python/

Comment: Have a read through https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting , which has an example very similar to your problem.

Comment: `(A[0], sorted(A[1], key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True))`

Comment: I don't get why this question has recieved three downvotes..

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli looking at the close votes, people didn't seem to understand the question. You could  just have written "I have this tuple, containing a tuple and a list of tuples. I want to sort the inner list by the first element of each of its elements". Instead you want to "order the object by score and value", which is less clear. Some of the downvotes may also have come from people who value an initial attempt by the OP.

Comment: Ok i realised quite soon that it was unclear. Now I think it's better. Thanks @timegb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just sort the list and be done.

```
In [1]: t = ('100460040',
   ...:  [(0.424943345091376, '100460139'),
   ...:   (0.5341613659423828, '100462023'),
   ...:   (0.2915704982169979, '100464122'),
   ...:   (0.6915704982169979, '100461026')])
   ...:   
In [2]: t[1].sort(reverse=True)
In [3]: 
In [3]: t
Out[3]: 
('100460040',
 [(0.6915704982169979, '100461026'),
  (0.5341613659423828, '100462023'),
  (0.424943345091376, '100460139'),
  (0.2915704982169979, '100464122')])
```

You don't need any extra effort to sort by the first element of each tuple, because tuples are sorted lexicographically anyway. The algorithm only looks at the second elements if the first elements are the same for a pair of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

If your tuple is named as `tpls`, then you can sort all the lists within that tuple as follows

```
tuple(sorted(t, reverse=True) if type(t) == list else t for t in tpls)
# ('100460040', [(0.6915704982169979, '100461026'), (0.5341613659423828, '100462023'), (0.424943345091376, '100460139'), (0.2915704982169979, '100464122'), (0.2915704982169979, '100461025'), (0.27074189424335177, '100410120'), (0.1915704982169979, '100461066'), (0.10862458037004655, '100490118')])
```

Comment: No need for the `key` or the `itemgetter` here.

Comment: @timgeb. Yes indeed. Update the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given an input tuple `T`:

```
T_sorted = (T[0], sorted(T[1], reverse=True))
```

We use the fact that tuples are sorted in Python naturally by element. In other words, sorting is performing first by element 0 of each tuple, then element 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the list is the the second element in your tuple, so it has index 1. So you can refer to the list as `t[1]` (assuming your tuple is called `t`; not a good name in real code). You can sort that simply with:

```
t[1].sort()
```

But in this case you want to sort from high to low, so you need

```
t[1].sort(reverse=True)
```

This works because the scores are the first element in each tuple in the list. If that weren't true, you would have to also pass an appropriate `key` function to sort().